# Does function gets executed all the time?

Tags: php, email

So I have a function in my wordpress custom theme witch I am using in all my forms. This function is in my wordpress functions.php and look like :

```
function mail_utf8($to, $subject = '(No subject)', $message = '', $from , $header = '') {
  $header_ = "From: $from" . "\r\n" . 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
  mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $message, $header_ . $header);
}
```

So the question is - Does this function is executing all the time, when some on refresh page? Or the function is executing only when I call it?

Because, I am getting from my host massages, that I have exceed the mail limit every hour. When I removed this function and hard coded in every form, everything is all right.

I tried :

```
if( !empty( $message ) ) {
 function mail_utf8($to, $subject = '(No subject)', $message = '', $from , $header = '') {
  $header_ = "From: $from" . "\r\n" . 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
  mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $message, $header_ . $header);
}
}
```

but it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have an opcode cache, this code is going to be *parsed* each time someone loads the page (loads/includes the file containing this code).

But it's only going to be *executed* when someone calls it.

Note: there is no point of specifying default arguments before `$from` because that field is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Function executes only when something calls it. Calling function looks like `some_fnc(arg1, arg2)`.

What you showed us is a function declaration. To actually call it one should write `mail_utf8('some@email.com')`. Look for it in your code and comment out if needed with `\\` symbols.

What you did actually can cause fatal error now: when something will try to call `mail_utf8()` without `$message` set function will not be declared and script will exit with error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mail_utf8()
```